# VS Code & WSL2 - specify Java Language Level to 1.8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code in WSL2 and have installed a bunch of Java Extensions as per [this link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial) - normal Java programs work well - able to Run & Debug from VS Code.

Although when I start using Java 8 specific features like Lambda, it starts complaining about the source level for Java 
[image: Java 8 features]

I've the following environment variables configured for Java Home 
[image: Configure Java Dev]

What property should be specified in Settings to determine the source level as 1.8 and not lower !

Edit: 
The bottom blue bar says the current Java Runtime is J2SE1.5 for some reason. See Attached [image: J2SE1.5]

On clicking, it asks to add the following property: `java.configuration.runtimes` and so I've added the following in my WSL2 settings for VS Code - still no effect !

```
"java.configuration.runtimes": [
{
  "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
  "path": "/usr/lib/jvm/zulu-8-amd64",
  "default": true
}
```

]

Comment: Do you use Maven? if you using maven, you need to set the maven-compiler-plugin source and target elements to 1.8: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html.

Comment: No maven here - just a simple Java program with public static void main... Want to do some quick testing/prototyping.....

Comment: Maybe a little stupid question, but, had you check your java version through 'java -version'?

Comment: And out of vscode, in WSL2, can you compile a .java file which use lambda, or it just not working in vscode?

Comment: yes its not working just in VS code. Works well outside. The trouble is how to configure the source level to 1.8 in VS Code. Even after setting the JAVA_HOME correctly in VS Code it looks like its defaulting to 1.5 or something lower than 1.8...

Comment: As you Run or Debug in vscode, the terminal should outputs like this:
'c:\Users\xxx\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-0.26.0\scripts\launcher.bat' 'D:\workSoft\JDK8\bin\java.exe' '-agentlib:j...
it's points to the right path as in the picture '/usr/lib/jvm/zulu-8-amd64'?

Comment: yes it gives  /usr/lib/jvm/zulu-8-amd64/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp /tmp/cp_3bl6xe1bmfh5li4tfvl8iuxc7.jar com.github.agrajm.mypackage.MyTestClass
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
        Lambda expressions are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above

Comment: Editing the question after finding more about configuring build environment.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got my answer from [Gitter](https://gitter.im/Microsoft/vscode-java-debug) that it picks up the language level settings from build file of the project. So I added a basic POM file with proper source & target config for maven-compiler-plugin and restarted IDE. Voila, it works !

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.8.1</version>
<configuration>
    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you give some more details about what you did? I have Java 13 installed but it is showing me as language level J2SE-1.5. I am unable to figure out how to fix this. I can't even use var keyword.

Comment: Hi @Aamir are you using a Maven based project? If yes then you can configure the maven-compiler-plugin with your Java versions and the IDE will pick from there. I edited my answer to include a snippet

Comment: Thanks. I had to specify 1.13 as maven.compiler.source and target to make VSCode realize that I am on Java 13

Answer (score 1):

I think if you use jdk 11 or later, you maybe find that no matter how you configure `settings.json` file, the language level never change.

The problem is eclipse's setttings. in `${WorkSpaceRoot}\.setting\org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs`, there are 3 settings: `targetPlatform`, `compliance`, `source`, need to change to `1.8` or later version.

And in `.classpath` file:

```xml
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8">
```

you can see there's a `JavaSE-1.8`, you can change it to other version(which should meets the eclipse settings).

Also there's a quick way to do this: vscode can search in the workspace to find the number(in your case is `1.5`), and replace them.

Answer (score 0):

I use the spring framework with gradle, lombok plugin and skdman (aside gradle, for maven is as good as well, I recommend use'em, they are all great), but I believe my configurations can be useful for everyone, so here it goes ...

One thing I may add thought its I got strange errors using plugins with command line gradle wich was corrected when i start using the vscode plugins interfaces only, therefor i would recommend give it a try and use the plugins buttons, if you have not done it yet.

At launch.json I have the following debug configurations:

```
{
  "name": "Spring Project ???",
  "type": "java",
  "request": "launch",
  "cwd": "${workspacefolder}",
  "console": "internalConsole",
  "mainClass": "br.com.meuProject.???",
  "projectName": "???",
  "args": []
}
```

- Note that the cwd is like workspacefolder, but you can change it to other values ​​like fileDirname, however in these cases it may be legal to also define the value of the variable "program"

In settings.json I have the following environment settings:

```
"java.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true,
"java.configuration.checkProjectSettingsExclusions": false,
"java.home": "C:\\Users\\name\\.sdkman\\candidates\\java\\current",
"java.jdt.ls.vmargs": "-XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:GCTimeRatio=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90 -Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -Xmx1G -Xms100m -javaagent:\"/home/user/.vscode/extensions/gabrielbb.vscode-lombok-1.0.1/server/lombok.jar\"",
```

- Note "java.home" defines you're JAVA_HOME variable.
- Note "java.jdt.ls.vmargs" defines the variables passed to command line whenever building java.

Hope to be of some use. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to configure my java runtime which is using java 7. (view -> command palette -> configure java runtime). Here change java version to java 8 or later.